# Postfix restriction classes for virtual alias

Tags: email, postfix

Hey we use postfix as Mailsystem and the config contain virtual alias table for address verification. We also use a simple List for administrative use. The list is in /etc/postfix/virtual written as "test@domain.tld   userxy"

The list and usermappings works fine but the problem is that we want protect some adresses for internal use only. So i add following lines to main.cf

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
      check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/protected_destinations,
      permit_mynetworks, 
      permit_sasl_authenticated, 
      reject_unauth_destination

smtpd_restriction_classes = insiders_only 
insiders_only = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/insiders, reject
```

The file protected_destinations contain:

```
test@domain.tld             insiders_only
```

The file insiders contain:

```
domain.tld        DUNNO
```

Output from postconf -n:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailbox_transport = cyrus
message_size_limit = 0
mydestination = domain.tld,domain2.tld
myhostname = domain.tld
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.100.0/24
myorigin = /etc/mailname
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = domain.tld
relayhost = [x.x.x.x]
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,        permit_sasl_authenticated,        reject_unauth_destination,   hash:/etc/postfix/access,   hash:/etc/postfix/virtual-user_access
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
virtual_alias_domains = /etc/postfix/virtual-domains
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
```

But it dosent work, i can send mail from external Address to test@domain.tld can anyone explain what i do wrong?

Here is a Logfile about a mail from extern to test@domain.tld:

```
Apr 19 16:57:34 serverx postfix/smtpd[15963]: 777A51762F1: client=smarthost.host[192.168.100.xy], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=userxy
Apr 19 16:57:34 serverx postfix/cleanup[15966]: 777A51762F1: message-id=<20120419145859.37090@externedomain.tld>
Apr 19 16:57:34 serverx postfix/qmgr[15959]: 777A51762F1: from=<address@externedomain.tld>, size=1720, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
Apr 19 16:57:34 serverx postfix/pipe[15972]: 777A51762F1: to=<interneruser@domain.tld>, orig_to=<test@domain.tld>, relay=cyrus, delay=0.24, delays=0.06/0.01/0/0.17, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via cyrus service)
Apr 19 16:57:34 serverx postfix/pipe[15969]: 777A51762F1: to=<interneruser2@domain.tld>, orig_to=<test@domain.tld>, relay=cyrus, delay=0.24, delays=0.06/0/0/0.18, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via cyrus service)
Apr 19 16:57:34 serverx postfix/qmgr[15959]: 777A51762F1: removed
```

Comment: Please add relevant logs showing this not working, and include the full output of `postconf -n` in your post.

Comment: What kind of log you need? When i try to send a mail from user@extern.tld to list@domain.tld then the mailserver accept the mail for deliver but he should reject this mail

Comment: @kockiren: From where did you try to send the mail? `127.0.0.0/8` and `192.168.1.100.0/24` are listed in your `mynetworks`, which means those are trusted and mail originating from those addresses will be accepted, no matter what. Try from some not-listed address, the behaviour should change.

Comment: Thx, i receive mails from a smarthost in the same network. How can i add a rule to check the restriction in case of both machine has the same IP Network?

Comment: Put the access list BEFORE permit_mynetworks, of course. Don't forget to switch OK to DUNNO in that case!

Comment: THX but this dosent work. I update the Question with Logfile and your Comments

Answer (score 2):

In order to restrict access to internal lists we have the follwoing:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
hash:/etc/postfix/access
hash:/etc/postfix/virtual-users_access
```

Then in the /etc/postfix/acccess map we have things like

```
all@          permit_mynetworks,reject
list2@        permit_mynetworks,reject
```

And in virtual-users_access things like

```
anonymous@domain     permit_mynetworks,reject
user1@domain        permit_mynetworks,reject
user2@domain        permit_mynetworks,reject
```

Comment: I try it but it dosent work. I can send mail from external Adress to test@domain.tld or in your example list2@domain.tld